# twitter ios4 ..Accounts Framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController

I followed twitter integration here for supporting twitter for both ios5 and ios4.

```
if ([DETweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {

    DETweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(DETweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch (result) {
            case DETweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Twitter Result: Cancelled");
                break;
            case DETweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"Twitter Result: Sent");
                break;
        }
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };

    DETweetComposeViewController *tcvc = [[[DETweetComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [tcvc addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YawkeyBusinessDog.jpg"]];
    [tcvc addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.DoubleEncore.com/"]];
    [tcvc addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#twitter"]];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentModalViewController:tcvc animated:YES];

} 
else {
    self.oAuth = [[[OAuth alloc] initWithConsumerKey:kDEConsumerKey andConsumerSecret:kDEConsumerSecret] autorelease];
    TwitterDialog *td = [[[TwitterDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    td.twitterOAuth = self.oAuth;
    td.delegate = self;
    td.logindelegate = self;
    [td show];
}
```

The tutorial didn't specify what is self.oAuth so i imported oAuth in my interface file and declared oAuth as a property

I have the following problems now :

1) the code above worked when i didn't put the completion handler block, after adding the handler the build is failing with error in DETweetAccountSelectorViewControllerDelegate  in line

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

saying no such file or directory exist... which it didn't when there was no completion handler. And yes i have now linked and unlinked to accounts framework more than 5 times now..so it was working before not now.

2) when i run the project without completion handler the twitter dialog pops up. but can't post(authorization request comes up for my twitter app but after authorizing it gets stuck) ..the log in console is

**discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:**

also if i close the dialog ..the program crashes because there is no code to dimiss the controller which i tried to solve using completion handler.

3) if any one have a simpler tutorial to integrate twitter for both ios4 and ios5 ..can you share..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer..there tutorial takes you in the opposite direction..waste my 5 hours on it..
just have to initialize DETweetComposeViewController ..and the rest is taken care of.. in their tutorial.. they show twitter dialog .and can tweet function which will just confuse

Answer (score 0):

I have recently received the:

discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:

Error in a different twitter framework that I am using.

The solution to the problem was that I had an error in my Delegate Function twitterDidLogin.

I think that if you solve for the error which you have not included on this post, that the 'discarded an uncaught exception' error will go away.  Maybe you could paste that error?